# Reading input from a system command in Haskell

Tags: haskell, process, io, system

hi I need to read <s>the command line</s> **standard out** after executing a haskell command, i know there are two modules to execute system commands: `System.Cmd` and `System.Process`

can anybody show me a simple example how to run the `System.Process` functions?

here is a example what i need to do (i know there is `System.Directory` to do that but i thought this is a good example):

1. execute a system command like `ls -a`
2. now i dont want the user to see the output
3. the output should only be accessable in my program to validate it

how can i do that?

Comment: I think you mean read a command's *output*, not read the *command line*. The command line means the name of the command being executed and its arguments.

Comment: The edit to the question is confusing. I interpreted the original as asking about reading the new process' **standard out** rather than **in**.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
import System.Process
test = readProcess "ls" ["-a"] ""
```

Do refer to the [documentation](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/libraries/process-1.6.5.1/System-Process.html) for usage details.

Comment: @Tarrasch The "ls" command is of course not platform independent, but readProcess should be. The documentation for `System.Process` mentions various areas where Windows' behavior deviates from the Unix-based platforms.

Comment: It's better to use [readProcessWithExitCode](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37108680/1100107).

Comment: Documentation link is dead, and this no solution no longer works.