# Binding the result of a system command to a variable in Haskell

Tags: haskell, system

How does one run a system command in Haskell **and** bind it's result (i.e., standard output) to a variable? In pseudo-haskell I'm looking for something like the following:

```
import System.Process

main = do output <- callCommand "echo hi"
          putStrLn output -- result: "hi"
```

This does not work. Is there something similar that does?

Comment: use [`readProcess`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/process-1.4.2.0/docs/System-Process.html#v:readProcess) instead of `callCommand`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is some working code:

```
import System.Process

main :: IO ()
main = do
  let stdin' = ""
  (errCode, stdout', stderr') <- readProcessWithExitCode "echo" ["hi"] stdin'
  putStrLn $ "stdout: " ++ stdout'
  putStrLn $ "stderr: " ++ stderr'
  putStrLn $ "errCode: " ++ show errCode
```

As Carsten notes, you can use readProcess, but I prefer this version because with any serious usage, you will soon be very confused as to why your command is silently failing (if you run in the command line, both stdout and stderr are, of course, shown).

Comment: Remark: don't use the names `stdout`, `stderr` or `stdin` if you want to use `System.IO` in the same context, since `System.IO` exports those names as `Handle` to the standard streams.

Comment: @jamshidh: I made a follow-up question to this answer in another post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37197388/binding-the-entire-output-of-an-ongoing-system-process-to-a-variable-in-haskell

Comment: @jamshidh Do you know [why this command fails?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38959402/how-to-use-readprocesswithexitcode)

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on jamshidh's answer, if instead of getting stdout and stderr as `String` you want to get them as `ByteString` or `Text`, you can use the [process-extras](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/process-extras) package.

You can also use my [process-streaming](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/process-streaming) package:

```
$ import System.Process.Streaming
$ execute (piped (shell "echo foo")) (liftA3 (,,) (foldOut intoLazyBytes)    
                                                  (foldErr intoLazyBytes)
                                                  exitCode)
("foo\n","",ExitSuccess)
```

Also for `Text`:

```
$ import System.Process.Streaming.Text
$ execute (piped (shell "echo foo")) (liftA3 (,,) (foldOut (transduce1 utf8x intoLazyText)) 
                                                  (foldErr (transduce1 utf8x intoLazyText)) 
                                                  exitCode)
("foo\n","",ExitSuccess)
```