# Binding the entire output of an ongoing system process to a variable in Haskell

Tags: haskell, process

The following snippet of code executes a `grep` command and binds the output to `stdout'`, `stderr'` and `errCode` respectively.

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    let stdin' = ""
    (errCode, stdout', stderr') <- readProcessWithExitCode "grep" ["search-term" ,"-nr", "/path/to/be/searched"] stdin'
    putStrLn $ "stdout: " ++ stdout'
    putStrLn $ "stderr: " ++ stderr'
    putStrLn $ "errCode: " ++ show errCode
```

The problem is that `stdout'` only captures the **first result** of the search. I think this is because `grep` is something akin to a spawned process that feeds search results one file by one file until it is finished.

**Question:** I need the **entire output** of the standard output of grep to be binded to `stdout'`. Is this possible in Haskell, and if so, what is an idiomatic way to do it?

**EDIT:** It turns out that the issue wasn't as I thought it was. Namely, I had only one file in my directory that wasn't symlinked. I forgot to use `-R` as an option with `grep`, and so those symlinks weren't being traversed in the search! The issue has been resolved.

Comment: I just tried this code, and got all the matches....  Can you show us your output?

Comment: Yes, I'll get some output and post above; however, are all of your matches coming from the same file? If so, that's what I get as well; however, if they are coming from more than one file, I only get matches for one file.

Comment: @jamshidh: you're right. The issue had to do with symlinks!