# How to use readProcessWithExitCode?

Tags: haskell

This command runs fine in my terminal:

```
grep --include=\\*.txt --recursive --regexp='answer'
```

This one runs fine in ghci:

```
import System.Process
r <- readCreateProcessWithExitCode (shell "grep --include=\\*.txt --recursive --regexp='answer'") ""
```

But this one fails in ghci:

```
import System.Process
r <- readProcessWithExitCode "grep" ["--include=\\*.txt", "--recursive", "--regexp='answer'"] ""
```

It returns `(ExitFailure 1,"","")`.

Am I doing something bad?

### Update

This one works:

```
readProcessWithExitCode "grep" ["-r", "-e 'answer'"]
```

It looks like one cannot set options starting with `--`.

Comment: I guess, "*.txt" is getting expanded by the shell in first case?

Comment: You should be able to use: `readProcess... "grep" ["-r", "-e", "answer"]`. Also see my updated answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure that this command work in your terminal:

```
grep --include=\\*.txt --recursive --regexp='answer'
```

On my system I get the warning:

```
grep: warning: recursive search of stdin
```

Try adding `.` as an additional argument:

```
readProcessWithExitCode "grep" ["--include=\\*.txt", "--recursive", "--regexp='answer'", "."] ""
```

**Update**

This simpler way of passing arguments to `grep` works for me:

```
readProcessWithExitCode "grep" ["--include", "*.hs", "--recursive", "--regexp", "answer", "."] ""
```

Comment: Yes ! It works with `"--include", "*.txt"` instead of `"--include=\\*.txt"`. That was the problem, there's no problem with `.` (for me).

Comment: It turns out I have an older version of `grep` - newer ones automatically assume `.` if you use `-r` with no directories.