# How to use readProcessWithExitCode ? (part 2)

Tags: haskell

Follow-up of [How to use readProcessWithExitCode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38959402/how-to-use-readprocesswithexitcode).

The following terminal command works fine:

```
$ grep "run" ./*.hs
```

It finds all the hs files containing the string "runr" in the current directory only.

But this command in Haskell returns an exit code (even when there are some matching files):

```
Prelude System.Process> readProcessWithExitCode "grep" ["run", "./*.hs"] ""
```

So how does `readProcessWithExitCode` (or `readProcess`) deal with the list of arguments, exactly ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run the command in the shell the shell expands the "glob" `./*.hs` to all of the file names in the current directory ending in `.hs`.

So the `grep` command never sees the argument `./*.hs` - it will only see the actual .hs file names.

To get the shell to expand the glob pattern you have to use `readCreateProcessWithExitCode` with a CreateProcess value configured to call the shell:

```
readCreateProcessWithExitCode (shell "grep run ./*.hs")
```

However, you then have to worry about quoting and escaping arguments. For instance, if you
are grepping for `run this` you will have to add quotes around the

```
readCreateProcessWithExitCode (shell "grep 'run this' ./*.hs") ""
```

whereas with `readProcess` you would just use:

```
readProcess "grep" ["run this", ...] ""
```

and not worry that the first argument contains a space.

Using the [Glob](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/Glob-0.7.11) package you can perform the file globbing yourself:

```
import System.FilePath.Glob

main = do
  files <- glob "./*.hs"
  let args = ["run"] ++ files
  readProcess "grep" args ""
```

Comment: Ok I see. I didn't know `glob`. Thank you. I knew `readCreateProcess`, this is the workaround I used.

Comment: Just to complement, I've just found the [path library](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/path) which is very nice to convert between absolute paths and relative paths (glob returns absolute paths).